# Help on setting up correct path for sites in multisite-setup

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I have a multisite installation and I have the following sites:

1. Root(site path: `/`)
2. Root English(site path: `/en`)
3. About(site path:`/about`)
4. **About English(site path: `/en/about`) **

The problem is with 4, I can't get the path to work. This is a multilingual setup and I want to have `example.com/about` and `example.com/en/about` or `example.com/about/en`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add a line of code in wp-config.php.

Code is:

```
define ('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

- Now refresh your dashboard and see in TOOLS a new option is there as
  Network Setup.
- Click on it and install it.
- It give you code to write
  in two files i.e. wp-config.php and .htaccess  write it and again
  login. You will see a network option in My Sites, click it and then you can make
  multisites.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining, I have a multisite installation and it works fine. I can create multiple sites. The problem is with the specific path-site, I wan to create.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I was looking for http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/. This plugins adds the URL Modification I need for the multilingual setup i was looking for. You can choose between the following:

1. Use Query Mode (?lang=en)
2. Use Pre-Path Mode (Default, puts /en/ in front of URL)
3. Use Pre-Domain Mode (uses http://en.yoursite.com)